# how to parse data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

Use the free REST API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to get
     100 albums. And display all the albums on the html page as:

```
 UserId: value of userId from the object that came to you,
 Id: Id value from the object that came to you,
 Title: title value from the object that came to you
 As a result, 100 different albums should be parsed on your page.
```

I tried to parse data and the data becomes a JavaScript object using JSON.parse() but data is showed in json format

```
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
 const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums";
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     this.responseText;
   }
 };

 xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: So what is the error? if JSON.parse() throws an error sounds like it is not valid JSON.

Comment: I add JSON.parse(.....) it doesnt work

Comment: I tried your code and JSON.parse worked. `var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(obj)` So not sure what you are doing wrong. Make an example that shows the error. Look in the console for errors.

Comment: it's working in console.log() but in html page it doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work ? Does it print `[object Object]` ?

Comment: Well that code button is not attached to anything, there is no demo element. So unless you give the exact code you are using, nothing I can do since I tested it and it was fine.

Comment: sorry, I'll edit my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you add a `<div id="demo"></div>`:

```js
function loadDoc() {
 const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums";
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     this.responseText;
   }
 };

 xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```